# Force apply with kubectl apply despite no changes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

`kubectl apply` does not apply since the file does not change, below is the content `mci.yaml` (just for reference, not essential).

```
apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: MultiClusterIngress
metadata:
  name: terraback-ingress
  namespace: terraback
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      backend:
        serviceName: terraback-mcs
        servicePort: 4000
```

Below is the command and response

```
(base) PS D:\terraform_small\terra-back> kubectl apply -f mci.yaml
multiclusteringress.networking.gke.io/terraback-ingress unchanged
```

But I need it to force apply, since `terraback-mcs` has changed, but is there a way to force apply despite no changes with `kubectl apply`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? I'd recommend to read what the apply command does exactly, because trying to change a resource  exactly matching your yaml with apply makes no sense. Also you shouldn't need to change your ingress just because something internal in your service changed afaik.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you do not need to update the Ingress spec since neither the service name nor port has changed. But if you really to force a replacement, you can try: `kubectl replace -f mci.yaml --force`

Answer (score 0):

> Below is the command and response
>
> ```
> (base) PS D:\terraform_small\terra-back> kubectl apply -f mci.yaml
> ```

`-f` doesn't mean force - it means file, you need `--force`, so:

```
kubectl apply -f mci.yaml --force
```

See [apply docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#apply):

[image]